# Why is appendChild of a script node, not executing natively

Tags: javascript, iframe, appendchild

My following code will only alert once from Firebug, using jQuery's append. I was pretty certain anytime a script tag hits the DOM, it executes immediately - iframe or not.

```
var iframe        = document.getElementById('myiframe'),
    iframe_window = iframe.contentWindow,
    iframe_head   = iframe_window.document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0],
    script        = iframe_window.document.createElement('script');

script.type      = 'text/javascript';
script.innerHTML = "alert(1);";

iframe_head.appendChild( script.cloneNode( true ) );
$(iframe_head).append( script.cloneNode( true ));
```

For added confusion I used jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/vs8KV/ ) and it DID alert twice. Do you think this is a Firebug issue or something else?

Comment: You mean, you're executing the above code from within Firebug's JavaScript console? Does it work if you hard code it into the document?

Comment: Yes, it is from my JS console. The code in my actual script is a bit more complicated so I've been testing the concept in Firebug and JS Fiddle. I'm essentially trying to load a script in that loads an object so I can append and then do `iframe_window.object.load();`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behaviour.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that would be the answer but I couldn't imagine what would be in my iframe that could cause this different behavior. To be honest my iframe is the YUI text editor so I wonder if they overwrite any native functions in an odd way... i'm gonna put another iframe on that same page and see if it works the right way.

Comment: Yeah it definitely appears something is wrong within that iframe. I just ran this on firebug in the same page and everything worked as expected: `var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); iframe.src = '#'; iframe.id = 'myiframe'; document.body.appendChild(iframe);` followed by the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I left out an important detail... the iframe is an RTE. This means the iframe has designMode turned on, which in turn disallows JS from running inside. I had no idea about that before today.

It would *seem* that the JS was running through jquery by running in the parent instead. If I console logged the window from the jquery.append it would show the parent window and not the iframe.